# Type mismatch: inferred type is SectionPagerAdapter but RecyclerView.Adapter<(raw) RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>? was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, type-mismatch, fragmentpageradapter

I learned about SectionPagerAdapter & RecyclerViews and tried to create one after watching [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/m_Fdf70uiCQ?si=QylcON8nMZl8Ooi8). Everything was going fine until the end when I got an error while running the code

The error I get in my DetailUserActivity.kt is:

```
package com.dicoding.usergithub.ui.detail

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions
import com.dicoding.usergithub.databinding.ActivityDetailUserBinding

class DetailUserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_USERNAME = "extra_username"
    }

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailUserBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: DetailUserViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDetailUserBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val username = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME)

        if (username != null) {
            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(DetailUserViewModel::class.java)

            viewModel.setUserDetail(username)
            viewModel.getUserDetail().observe(this, { it ->
                if (it != null) {
                    binding.apply {
                        dName.text = it.name
                        dUsername.text = it.login
                        dFollowers.text = it.jlhFollowers.toString()
                        dFollowing.text = it.jlhFollowing.toString()
                        dLocation.text = it.location
                        Glide.with(this@DetailUserActivity)
                            .load(it.avatar_url)
                            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(dPicture)
                    }
                }
            })

            val sectionPagerAdapter = SectionPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
            binding.apply {
                viewPager.adapter = sectionPagerAdapter
                tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

[image][image]

I want this problem solved, I have tried it but it doesn't work well

Comment: Add ```SectionPagerAdapter``` code in your question